# Laying out a view with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to iOS development so the question may sound easy.

How can I layout a view like the one we can see in Facebook app's post details? At the top the post details can be seen, below that there are buttons to like comment etc and below that there is a scrollable comment list. At the bottom of the screen there is a static Add Comment section that never disappears.

Which controls should I use?

Comment: Have you attempted it on your own already? Most people would be more inclined to help you with a specific problem in your implementation instead of asking for someone to do it from scratch.

Comment: The facebook app is just a web browser, 1 view controller, and 2-3 layers to that view controller (to control the left and right tabs). Really its just one big web view that grabs information from the facebook server. Theres not much so say for iOS Developers... web developers do this kinda stuff.

Comment: @jszumski I am not asking anyone to do it from scratch. I don't want someone to code something for me. I am new to layout system and need some advice. I am sure lots of newcomers are kind of lost in the iOS implementation of layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Top part is a `UITableView`. The cell is big and is further subdivided in 3 parts (each cell will look the same).

- Part 1 has image, message, etc.
- Part 2 is just three button links.
- Part 3 is a button with a link as well. Links can be done with buttons, labels, etc.

Each item (example button) most likely has a method that loads that specific view. Because of the navbar they are most likely pushing the view on a navigation controller stack.

Bottom "slide" part is a view with a text field on top. Then when tapped it is animated and moved up, so it's visible on top of the keyboard.

Comment: Thank you waf. Really helped a lot.